# Laravel 8 Passport UUIDS

Tags: php, laravel-8

I just created new laravel 8 app and I have some issues with Laravel Passport UUIDS.
I have installed everything that I needed. Changed every passport migrations with `$table->uuid('id')->primary();`

Everything is just as default for example AuthServiceProvider just have `Passport::routes();`

I tried to follow https://mlo.io/blog/2018/08/17/laravel-passport-uuid/ instructions but It seems that it doesn't work.
When I run `php artisan passport:install --uuids` I receive error like:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `users`)
```

And yes, I have user_devices migration where I have foreign for oauth_access_tokens, but even if I add

```
public function register()
    {
        \Laravel\Passport\Passport::ignoreMigrations();
    }
```

In AppServiceProvider, it gives just the same error.

Anyone had same problem? Any relevant tutorial how to do this?

Comment: maybe you have to upgrade your db version

Comment: Well my version is Version information: 5.0.2 (up to date)

Comment: okay, then maybe you have to refresh migration php artisan migrate:refresh , cause usually migration error comes from previous existing data

Comment: Yup, did this as well, still same

Comment: Which migration is failing? I'm curious why it would need to drop the users table.